# HTML5 input type='number' not included in form serialization

Tags: html, serialization

I have a form as below.When I try to serialized, all fields except the number inputs are shown. But if try changing the type to text, then it is included in the serialization. Am I missing something?

- With number input

  ```
  <form id="contact-form">
     <input type='text' name="FullName" />
     <input type='number' name="Age" />
  </form>
  ```

form serialization output = `"FullName=Sam"`

- changing number type to text

  ```
  <form id="contact-form">
     <input type='text' name="FullName" />
     <input type='text' name="Age" pattern="[0-9]*"/>
  </form>
  ```

form serialization output = `"FullName=Sam&Age=23"`

serialize method -

```
function serializeObject(obj) {
    var o = {};
    var a = obj.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function () {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });

    return o;
}
```

Comment: At least you forgot to show us your serialization code.

Comment: @Kaiido I have added the serialization code

Comment: Now show how you call it. Read [ask], make sure your question contains a [mcve].

Comment: Some parts are still missing (like the stringification one). But what you gave until now does work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/47zce31t/

Answer (score -1):

**input[type='number']** will also work. Write it full way as **("input[type='number']" ).serialize();** . Or check your **Inverted commas** and **parentheses** are properly closed.

Comment: Do I need to specify it in selector? By default, form serialization should consider all valid HTML/HTML5 input controls?